# Why my state is not getting updated even after writing the setState method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Columns extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props)

```
    this.state={
        message:'Hello'
    }
}

changeMessage(){
    
     this.setState=({
         message:'Welcome'
    })
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div>{this.state.message}</div>
            <button onClick={this.changeMessage}>Click</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}
export default Columns

Comment: Both answers you received are right, though none of them is really necessary as `this.setState = ...` is a typo-like problem and the [`this` problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33973648/1218980) has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1218980) a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1218980) on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ray hatfield said above, you're losing the `this` context and need to use an arrow function, but also you're not calling `setState`; you're overriding it.

Remove the `=` from

```
this.setState=({
     message:'Welcome'
})
```

so that it says:

```
this.setState({
    message:'Welcome'
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Because passing it as `this.changeMessage` detaches it from the component scope. When the button invokes it, "this" is no longer the component.

Change it to an arrow function: `() => this.changeMessage()`

I've tried to explain this scope issue in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022019/converting-material-ui-to-a-class-in-react/58022081#58022081) in the past if you want the details.

Also, as [Aaron points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63179845/636077) you also have an extraneous `=` in your changeMessage handler.